# How to edit files directly on webdav in windows

Tags: windows, mount, webdav

I have a webDAV setup with the cPanel webdisk. I can connect to it through NetHood and I can drag and drop files to/from there. What I can't do is simply edit any of the files directly. I need to copy it somewhere else, edit it, then copy it back. That's essentially what is needed with ftp, though smart clients will monitor the file, making it easier than webDAV in the current state I'm using it in.

I was under the impression that webdav was supposed to let me work on the files as if it were a local drive. But nothing can actually open the files. How can I go about bringing more functionality around to it? Or is this as good as it gets?

I have tried 'net use q:\ https://myserver.com:2078' and 'net use q:\ '\myserver.com@SSL:2078\' but neither work and only throws: "System error 67 has occurred. The network name cannot be found."

I ultimately want to use TortiseSVN with the webDAV so I can have my working copy running on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried mounting as a remote drive and none of instructions I found worked on any computer I tried it on. net use doesn't work no matter what I try.

I've found 2 solutions:

[Novell NetDrive 4.1](http://www.theblog.ca/novell-netdrive) which is [kinda sort of free](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/qna/999.html) with some [docs](http://www.novell.com/documentation/ifolder21/?page=/documentation/ifolder21/netdrive/data/a2iii88.html).

And a [more recent program](http://www.netdrive.net/) also called [NetDrive](http://www.netdrive.net/) that is free for personal use.

There is also [WebDrive](http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/WebDAVClient.html) which is where Novel licensed its NetDrive from.  There is a [20day demo available](http://www.southrivertech.com/download/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check these articles [WebDAV in IIS 7 - Part 1](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-Configure-WebDAV-in-IIS-7-75.aspx) and [WebDAV in IIS 7 - Part 2](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-Configure-WebDAV-to-redirect-a-UserGroup-to-a-specific-folder-in-IIS-7-75-e28093-Part-2.aspx)

Comment: Nothing I have is running IIS.